# Fetchind data from foursquare api with knockoutJS to store the data and and add the markers on map using google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js, foursquare

This is my Html Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/map.css">
<script src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div> 
<div id= "heading"> <h3> Gym's in Tilak Nagar and nearby areas </h3> </div>

<div id ="menu" > 
<h1 id="header">List of places</h1>

<form class = "search">
    <input class ="input" data-bind = "value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Search from the list" >
    <button> Filter </button>
</form>
<div data-bind= "foreach: filteredPlaces" class = "list"> 
    <li class = "name" data-bind = "text:name, click: $parent.setMarker,$parent.toggleBounce"> </li>
</div>
</div>


<script src="js/lib/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script src = "main.js"> </script>

<script src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDaggBT_ca24SRBV3xs6oFzTbOWnrFJAjY&v=3&callback=initMap"></script>  

</body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript code.

```
var clientID = 'P3B45WXNAGYNYO4ZFIFQUANHVAZ4RPZZ4Z0DG4S3TRJWCQGF';  
var clientSECRET = 'R1RZ4KZQJYJJYX2F4NHWLXLXY10WIUXNKDFZU5SCNH0PBYBQ';

 var locations = [
    {
        name: 'Addiction Gym & Spa',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.639187518722093,
                    lng: 77.0750160873286
                },
        id: '51a414ad498eb4e0c8c79e1e'      
    },

    {
        name: 'Strength Gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.63951183622196,
                    lng: 77.08926957394918
                },
        id: '4fef06e2e4b02af6a2356eb1'  
    },
    {
        name: 'The gym vikaspuri',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.64290937981111,
                    lng: 77.08158661505388
                },
        id: '5032112fe4b01882fa165c1c'  
    },
    {
        name: 'The world gym vikas puri',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.64402685702688,
                    lng: 77.0864032751163
                },
        id: '50cefeede4b0e6c84cbe64ff'  
    },
    {
        name: 'Radius Gym And Spa',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.641996352813372,
                    lng: 77.09651931856945
                },
        id: '4f5d633ce4b082b23ee80b13'  

    },
    {
        name: 'The world gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.64487862367399,
                    lng: 77.07923160832262
                },
        id: '50cf0636e4b0b0b98db4ae54'  
    },
    {
        name: 'Brix Gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.627407338627094,
                    lng: 77.08603262901306
                },
        id: '4fd58007121dc5ba007f1a11'  
    },
    {
        name: 'The Gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.62630747520567,
                    lng: 77.09218638430356
                },
        id: '4e2e51e5d4c058fdbee8bb78'  
    },
    {
        name: 'Multy Gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.634479626908053,
                    lng: 77.07248670383318
                },
        id: '50194997e4b08d7eda13885f'  
    },
    {
        name: 'Carbon gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.62688669873087,
                    lng: 77.09476593210454
                },
        id: '506c557de4b092ceaefec3af'  
    },
    {
        name: 'Musclemania Gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.632213228257452,
                    lng: 77.10194229080281
                },
        id: '4d517187994dba7a58fe14ec'  
    },
    {
        name: 'Brix gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.634499063442853,
                    lng: 77.1051004269293
                },
        id: '52818963498e05f204e735b9'  
    },
    {
        name: 'Gym X',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.616414801933328,
                    lng: 77.08061988756133
                },
        id: '4e676b59e4cdfdecb047334f'  
    },
    {
        name: 'Adonis fitness and Gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.62156138091793,
                    lng: 77.0877802311305
                },
        id: '4e6c3d9cb993061ea8b781eb'      
    },
    {
        name: "'Gold's Gym A Block Janakpuri'",
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.622431823919275,
                    lng: 77.06936705764893
                },
        id: '4f8818c2e4b013a97f3b8841'  
    },
    {
        name: 'Gold Gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.621837221762117,
                    lng: 77.0695750365762
                },
        id: '4e24f73db0fbf642a8fac7ba'  
    },
    {
        name: 'Gymplex',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.63941226079242,
                    lng: 77.08104142666788
                },
        id: '509bd5bae4b0eaba8f4768be'  
    },
    {
        name: 'The Gym',
        latlng: {
                    lat: 28.626682205745386,
                    lng: 77.09179401397705
                },
        id: '4dc00c7a4159b09a64c3782a'      
    }
];



var Location = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = data.name;
    self.latlng = data.latlng;
    self.id = data.id;
    self.distance = ko.observable(data.distance);
};

var map, marker;

var viewModel = function() {

    self = this;

    this.names = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.markers = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.locationList = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.foursquareApi = function() {   



    locations.forEach(function(location) {
        self.locationList.push(new Location(location));
    });

    var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';

    var largeInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (var i=0; i < self.locationList().length; i++) {

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: self.locationList()[i].latlng,
            animation: null,
            title: locations[i].name,
            content: '',
            draggable: true,
            visible: true,
            icon: image,
            id: i
        });
        self.markers().push(marker);

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            populateInfoWindow(this, largeInfoWindow);
          });
         marker.addListener('click', function() {
           toggleBounce(this);
          });
        self.locationList()[i].marker = marker; 

    };

    var populateInfoWindow = function (marker, infowindow) {

        if (infowindow.marker != marker) {
          infowindow.marker = marker;
          infowindow.setContent('<div>' + '<h4>' + marker.title + '</h4>'  +  marker.content + '</div>');
          infowindow.open(map, marker);

          infowindow.addListener('closeclick', function() {
            infowindow.marker = null;
          });
        }
      };

    self.query = ko.observable('');

    self.filteredPlaces = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locationList(), function (rec) {
            if ( self.query().length === 0 || rec.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                    rec.marker.setVisible(true);
                    return true; 
                    } else {
                    rec.marker.setVisible(false);
                    return false;
                    }
                });
            });

    self.setMarker = function(data) {
         self.locationList().forEach(function (location){
              location.marker.setVisible(false);    
            }); 

            data.marker.setVisible(true);

             data.marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
              setTimeout (function () {
                     data.marker.setAnimation(null);
            }, 2000); 
            map.setCenter(data.marker.position);
            }


        /*  setTimeout (function () {
                    location.marker.setVisible(true);
            }, 5000); 

        };*/

    var toggleBounce= function(marker)  {
        if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            setTimeout (function () {
            marker.setAnimation(null)
            }, 1000);
        }
    };

    self.locationList().forEach(function(item) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: false,
                url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search',
                data: 'client_id='+clientID+'&client_secret='+clientSECRET+'&v=20130815&ll='+item.latlng.lat+','+item.latlng.lng+'&query='+item.name,
                success: function(data) {

                            item.marker.title =  data.response.venues[0].name ; 
                            item.marker.content = ' Distance: '+ (data.response.venues[0].location.distance)/1000 + " km's" + '</br>' + '   CheckinCount: ' + data.response.venues[0].stats.checkinsCount;          
                        }

            });
        });
    };
    self.foursquareApi();
};


var styles = [
    {
      stylers: [
        { hue: "#00ffe6" },
        { saturation: -20 }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "road",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [
        { lightness: 100 },
        { visibility: "simplified" }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "road",
      elementType: "labels",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    }
  ];




 function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {lat: 28.632213228257452 , lng: 77.09179401397705 },
    styles: styles

  });

   ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
}
```

I have a hard-coded list of locations but I want to use the locations list received from them foursquare API and append that to self.locationList array, I know how to push the data inside the array and it is also getting pushed but the problem is data from foursquare API arrives after some time and till then all the code gets executed. Kindly help me out, I am stuck here for a while and I don't want to use the hard-coded locations. I have used knockout JS in this project. There is a toggle function that bounces the marker when clicked, set marker function displays the marker when list of gyms is clicked on the right side. So I want all these to work.

This is my CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#menu {
    width: 22%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    }

#heading {
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 30%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: skyblue;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    }

.list, .search, #header{
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

.input{
        width: 225px;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 1px solid #19A7E2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that JavaScript promises would help you out with your problem.

Check out this link: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-coding-with-promises

Comment: Hey @Gary thanks for replyin but I did not understand what was the link trying to teach me because I am a newbee into web development. if there is any simple way to achieve this please let me know. I have an idea that I should make a function that will initiate inisde the success function or when the success function is true. How should I achieve that ?

Comment: Ok.  I didn't realize that you may not understand the JavaScript on that link.  Let me put together a JSFiddle or Plunkr for you later today.

Comment: Here's the JSFilddle.  I cannot get your original map markers to load correctly.  The map displays but no markers at all.

There is a console error regarding something in your code though.  Something having to do with knockoutJS and your bindings...


Add your map.css file contents in the css pane on the jsfiddle too.



https://jsfiddle.net/1rtz57L5/6/